# best options for flowing dotted lines (svg path animation) in ie?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, internet-explorer-9

I've been assigned to create a chart with dotted lines (paths) that flow to circles in a chart.  I was given a prototype to start with that was based on d3.js using the following example:

http://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/6354551

However the url above doesn't work in IE, not even the latest version. I need to support IE back to IE9. My svg animation requirements are fairly basic. Only flowing lines (svg paths) between circles are required.

What would be the most elegant way to support this requirement?  Looking for the most simple, straightforward approach that will support flowing svg paths to circles in all major browsers going back to IE9.

Comment: SImplest? Show IE9 users an animated gif.

Comment: looking for something reusable.  also the chart is dynamically generated with different params so a 1-off animated gif won't work for this.  thinking about using a js solution to animate the lines.  seems like it could be the most straightforward solution

Comment: looks like there are several js libs that will do some advanced svg animation like this one https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/.  however, my scenario is very basic - straight dotted lines animated to flow at variable speeds.  so I'm thinking that a simple function or handful of js functions can be used to accomplish what I need to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example code is doing the animation using some advanced CSS.  Here's the same animation written using a d3 [transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition).

**UPDATES**

The version below I wrote in d3 version 4 and doesn't seem to work in IE9...  Here's a d3 version 3 example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    .node {
      fill: #dddddd;
      stroke: gray;
      stroke-width: 4;
    }
    
    .flowline {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
      opacity: 0.5;
      stroke-width: 4;
      stroke-dasharray: 10, 4;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var width = 960,
      height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    var ex1 = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(50 50)');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M100 100 L300 100');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 L300 100');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 L300 250');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M300 250 L100 100');

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 100)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 200)
      .attr('cy', 300)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .attr('r', 20);

    var ex2 = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(450 50)');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M100 100 S200 0 300 100');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 S200 200 300 100');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 S300 350 300 250');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M300 250 L100 100');

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 100)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 200)
      .attr('cy', 300)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .attr('r', 20);

    function animate(){
      d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .ease('linear')
        .duration(1000)
        .styleTween("stroke-dashoffset", function() {
          return d3.interpolate(0, 14);
        })
        .each("end", animate);
    }

    d3.selectAll(".flowline")
      .each(animate);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Original Answer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aight/1.2.2/aight.d3.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  
  
  <style>
    .node {
      fill: #dddddd;
      stroke: gray;
      stroke-width: 4;
    }
    
    .flowline {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
      opacity: 0.5;
      stroke-width: 4;
      stroke-dasharray: 10, 4;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var width = 960,
      height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    var ex1 = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(50 50)');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M100 100 L300 100');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 L300 100');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 L300 250');

    ex1.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M300 250 L100 100');

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 100)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 200)
      .attr('cy', 300)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex1.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .attr('r', 20);

    var ex2 = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(450 50)');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M100 100 S200 0 300 100');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 S200 200 300 100');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M200 300 S300 350 300 250');

    ex2.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'flowline')
      .attr('d', 'M300 250 L100 100');

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 100)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 200)
      .attr('cy', 300)
      .attr('r', 20);

    ex2.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('cx', 300)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .attr('r', 20);
      
    animate();
    function animate() {
      d3.selectAll(".flowline")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .styleTween("stroke-dashoffset", function() {
          return d3.interpolate(0, 14);
         })
        .on("end", animate);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for putting that sample together.  it works well when I run it in ie11 as well as ie10 but crashes when I run it in ie9.  is an additional tweak needed for ie9?  I don't need to go further back than ie9 but I am required to support ie9.  doesn't d3 claim to support ie9?  or are polyfills/mixins required to support some scenarios for some browsers?

Comment: @user6867266, see updates above.  I didn't realize `d3` version 4 dropped IE9 support.  I rewrote it in `d3` version 3 and tested it in IE11 running IE9 emulation.  Seems to work.

Comment: thanks mark - your example works well.  thanks for putting it together.  I'm trying to incorporate your approach into a specific implementation that I'm working on. here's the svg with the path/flowline:[https://www.dropbox.com/s/svcx1lonuy9l267/NeSeFlow.svg?dl=0].  
Here's the html/js: [https://jsbin.com/timixuq/edit?html,output].  the solution works in ie10 but throws a d3 error in ie9.  will you please take a look and lmk if you see the problem?

Comment: @user6867266, it looks IE9 doesn't like the mixing of the that stroke attributes with the `stroke-dashoffset` style. Instead of `.styleTween("stroke-dashoffset"`, use `.attrTween("stroke-dashoffset"`...

Comment: thanks mark!  you're a life saver.  do you have a website with a "send a beer" button?

Comment: @user6867266, ha, ha, no beer necessary.  Glad it worked for you.